# Maximum Likelihood of random variable being Fréchet distributed with multiplicative noise?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, maximum-likelihood

I have a random variable being [Fréchet distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) with shape parameter $\nu$ and scale parameter $c$ (location $0$). Now I add multiplicative noise, i.e., I set:
$$
Y=X \cdot \epsilon \;,
$$
with epsilon being some noise.

Now I want to calculate the maximum likelihood estimators for $\nu$ and $c$ given realizations of $Y$ and want to know in particular if the ML estimators are asymptotically consistent;

What I thought about it: If I say that $\epsilon$ is lognormally-distributed with $\mu=0$ and some $\sigma^2$, then if I take the logarithm $\log(Y)=\log(X)+\epsilon_2$ with $\epsilon_2$ being normally distributed;
Now since the normal distribution with $\mu=0$ is symmetric around zero I think that the estimators of $\nu$ and $c$ might be asymptotically consistent.

Is this true? If yes - how can one see that?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add a reference for this not-so-classical distribution.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the likelihood for any set of parameters $\nu$, $c$, and $\sigma^2$ needs to be determined numerically (not to mention the numerical procedure for finding the maximum likelihood estimates).  That would seem to make determining if the maximum likelihood estimators are asymptotically consistent more than a bit difficult.  Have you constructed an explicit likelihood for $\log(Y)$?

Comment: @ Jean Marie: Thank you @JimB: What if I keep $\nu$ as a known and fixed constant and then apply the likelihood function based on the density of the FRECHET distribution only? I've just been running a simulation and it seems like we get something like convergence.. Might this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiplicative distributions, such as the log-normal distribution you already thought of, but also the Fréchet distribution, are well characterized with geometric statistic measures.

The geometric mean of a Fréchet-distributed variable $X$ with shape $\nu$, scale $c = 1$, and location $m = 0$ is
$$
\mathrm{GM}(X) = \exp\left( \dfrac{\gamma}{\nu} \right) \;,
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Where exactly in the hint going? That I should not use ML-estimators but work with the geometric mean? If I e.g. use the Geometric Mean I have: $\textrm{GM}(Y)=\textrm{GM}(X)\textrm{GM}(\epsilon)$ because for some numbers $x_1,...,x_n$ and $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ we have: $(x_1\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n)^{1/n}(\epsilon_1\cdot \ldots \cdot \epsilon_n)^{1/n}=(x_1\epsilon_1\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n\epsilon_n)^{1/n}$

Comment: BTW: What does your $c$ stand for? Location? Then you mean a Frechet distributed r.v. with shape $\nu$, scale $s=1$ and location $c=0$?

Comment: But I have only one geometric mean but three parameters to guess...

Comment: I think that what is being hinted at is the use of the method of moments (if for nothing else but to get reasonable starting values for the mle iterative procedure).  The mean of $\log(Y)$ will be the same as the mean of $\log(X)$ which is $\frac{\nu  \log (c)+\gamma }{\nu }$.  The variance of $\log(Y)$ will be $\frac{\pi ^2}{6 \nu ^2}+\sigma^2$.  That gets you 2 equations with 3 unknown parameters.